# Ternary operator and function signature

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, function-signature

Let's say I have a C++ class with two functions like

```
class MyClass
{
    bool Foo(int val);
    bool Foo(string val);
}
```

Is it possible to use the ternary operator like this

```
MyClassInstance->Foo(booleanValue?24:"a string");
```

and have a different function of `MyClass` invoked depending on the value of `booleanValue`?

Comment: Have you tried compiling and running it to see what happens?

Comment: This doesn't even compile. The compiler will complain about the different types of the ternary operator.

Comment: I do not understand the upvotes here. Sure, it's a fun experiment, but the question could have easily been avoided if the OP only *tried it*. The OP has not provided any research information at all.

Comment: I came from a PHP background and I got 3 downvotes immediately. damn some languages are just stubborn isn't it?

Comment: @Default I should have phrased my question differently: I have that code that does not compile, is there a way to get it compiling or is this notation forbidden? I will be more careful next time...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Not with the ternary operator. The type of a ternary expression is the common type of its second and third operands; if they have no common type you can't use it. So just use an ordinary `if` statement:

```
if (booleanValue)
    MyClassInstance->Foo(24);
else
    MyClassInstance->Foo("a string");
```

Answer (score 7):

The type of a ternary conditional expression is the common type two which both operands are con­ver­tible. You can definitely *not* perform "dynamic overload resolution", as you seem to be suggesting.

Since there is no common type for `int` and `char const *`, the code won't even compile (as you sure­ly noticed when you tested this).

(You may be thrilled to know that the ternary conditional is used precisely because of those semantics in the implementation of the `std::common_type` trait class template, together with `decltype`.)

(If the condition is known *statically*, such as `sizeof(int) != 7`, then you can use template spe­cia­lization to write similar-looking code that *does* perform conditional overload resolution, but of course statically.)

Answer (score 5):

No. To perform overload resolution the compiler will ask "what is the type of `booleanValue?24:"a string"`?". That question cannot be answered.

Comment: Cannot be answered *at compile-time* (not my down-vote BTW - just making a small suggestion to improve the answer)

Comment: @Paul In C++ expressions only have types at compile-time. It does not make sense to talk about something else.

Comment: Yes, I know, the point is that it is *conceivable* that you could determine which function to call dynamically, i.e. at run-time, but for C++ you need to know the type at compile-time.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is not permitted.

Overloads are compile-time, so it cannot work in runtime that way.

It is not common in code you would want to do exactly that, however sometimes with iostream there is a desire to do something like:

`os << ( condition ? var1 : var2 )`

where var1 and var2 have different types. That also doesn't work.

You could do:

```
MyClassInstance->Foo( booleanValue ? boost::any(24) : boost::any("a string") );
```